# how to remove all class from child node using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

- it have ul li structure menu.
- i want remove all menushow class from submenu_1.
- i have multiple submenu_1 class.

demo example :

```
<ul class="submenu_1 menushow">
<li class="sub">
    <ul class="submenu_2 menushow">
        <li>
            <ul class="submenu_2 menushow">
                <li>
                    <ul class="submenu_2 menushow">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: what you tried so far? where is you code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all class `.menushow` from elements from `ul.submenu_1.menushow` you can use `el.classList.remove('menushow')`:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('ul.submenu_1.menushow, ul.submenu_1 .menushow')
  .forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('menushow');
  })
```

```html
<ul class="submenu_1 menushow">
  <li class="sub">
      <ul class="submenu_2 menushow">
          <li>
              <ul class="submenu_2 menushow">
                  <li>
                      <ul class="submenu_2 menushow">
                          <li></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1. i have multiple ul with same class name to submenu_1                              2. i want remove menushow class only to click on particular ul.                        3. and also remove first menushow class on ul

Comment: You have to attach an event handler to the `ul` element you want to fire the solution execution on click

Comment: yes but this only remove first class. this is remove only submenu_1 with menushow